# RDLC Report export to Excel change column data type

Tags: export-to-excel, rdlc

While exporting to Excel i am not able to Convert column data type from General to Number or Currency. Its showing error on Excel cells "The Number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.". Can anyone provide me a link how to change column date type while exporting to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datatype as int32. [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the textbox in Tablix
2. Go to textbox properties
3. Go to Numbers tab
4. select Category "Number" and click ok.